# Error with attribute in libpcap

Tags: c++, libpcap, packet-sniffers, wifi

I'm using the code from [here](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/networksecuritytools/0596007949/networkst-CHP-10-SECT-3.html) to for 802.11 sniffing in monitor mode.

```
#define ETH_HEADER_SIZE 14
#define AVS_HEADER_SIZE 64                 /* AVS capture header size */
#define DATA_80211_FRAME_SIZE 24           /* header for 802.11 data packet */
#define LLC_HEADER_SIZE 8                  /* LLC frame for encapsulation */
/* SNAP LLC header format */
struct snap_header           
{
  u_int8_t dsap; 
  u_int8_t ssap;
  u_int8_t ctl;
  u_int16_t org; 
  u_int8_t org2;
  u_int16_t ether_type;          /* ethernet type */              
} __attribute__ ((__packed_  _));
```

I'm not quite an expert about c++, and I'm getting this error:

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘_’ warning: ‘__packed_’ attribute  
directive ignored [-Wattributes]  } __attribute__ ((__packed_  _));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page where you got that code added some bogus spaces to the `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` declaration.  It should be *exactly* as I wrote it there, with no spaces between any of the the underscores.